# Tensorflow.js support Mac M1 GPU

Tags: node.js, tensorflow.js

I am using tensorflow.js on node.js to create my machine learning project.

As I known that if tensorflow training can be used GPU, the training performance is faster.

Does tensorflow.js support Mac M1? It yes, how to make it possible? Thank you.
Tommy